# How to test a Meteor call in a client unit test in Jasmine?

Tags: meteor, jasmine

I'm using `Meteor 1.2.1` and `sanjo:jasmine@0.20.2`. I would expect this test (running on the client side) to fail, but it looks like it's never executed.

```
describe('compressListOfIntegers', function () {
  it('should return any string', function (done) {
    Meteor.call('compressListOfIntegers', [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], function(err, data) {
      expect(data).toEqual(jasmine.any(Number));
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

How can I test a Meteor.call? As an added bonus: should I test my Meteor methods from the client? What are the alternatives?

Comment: I'm now using Mocha with Meteor 1.4.4.2 and it works fine.